# What is the difference between installing regular Firebase & Firebase core in iOS?

Tags: ios, firebase, cocoapods

I am new in Firebase. According to their setup guide for iOS, when I'm creating new app to configure Firebase in console, I should add `pod 'Firebase'` in the podfile.

It was also mentioned that by default, this pod includes `firebase-analytics`. But then what is the use of `pod 'Firebase/Core'`? Since it also includes Analytics.

I'm really confused. Do I need to include `pod 'Firebase/Core'` too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to include pod 'Firebase/Core'. Core is the default subspec for pod 'Firebase' and will be automatically included from pod 'Firebase'. With the current Firebase pod organization, the purpose of Core is to include Analytics. This may change in the future.

Details in the [podspec](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/4.4.0/Firebase.podspec.json).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: The Link is broken

Comment: @joao2fast4u Fixed link.